# Is it permissible for a woman to befriend or talk to man?

Tags: sunni, women

If a woman talks to a man is it considered as zina?

Nowadays, almost every college going girl has male friends. So if one's intentions are not wrong is it still haram for a women to make friendship with men?

Comment: Your statement `almost every college going girl has male friends` is a general one referring to all girls of the world or only Muslims? If it is the later one, is it your assumption or you have a source?

Answer (score 3):

Zina is fornication or sexual intercourse.  Talking to a male is not zina but it may lead to such an act if boundaries of male-female relationship are not set right. There is no harm in discussion related to studies but be careful. If you make sure that you are not alone but in a group, then it is preferred. Company and circumstances matter a lot. If a girl meets a boy over a college party or vice versa, thing look fishy to begin with.

Female's talking to male is not haraam if the objective or destination of the friendship is not haraam.